# Issue making HTTP post request with json

Tags: java, android, rest, http, post

My request code can be seen here:

```
public static void execute() {
    Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();
    comment.put("sourceCode", "int x = 0;");
    comment.put("language", "54");
    comment.put("input", "");
    String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);
    HttpResponse response = makeRequest("http://api.compilers.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/submissions?access_token" +
            "=a3bdc6343aa21ebe9f28ecd7c8a8c43f", json);
    try {
        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("Response", responseStr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static HttpResponse makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
        Log.d("ResponseLate", EntityUtils.toString(httpPost.getEntity()));
        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The request is made to the server, but not using my JSON, so I am getting the an error message back in my response that I am missing required parameters.

In the makeRequest method I log the httpPost.getEntity() and get this value

```
06-04 01:21:45.814  24533-24736/me.dylanredfield.testbase3 D/ResponseLate﹕ {"input":"","language":"54","sourceCode":"int x \u003d 0;"}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: For your code I'm getting `{"error":"WRONG_LANG_ID"}` I'm using `httpclient-4.3.3`

Answer (score 0):

you haven't pass the content-type so the server failed to recognize the type of request...

set

```
httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json");
```

befor setentity()